# Transform this table. With something like "coalasce" for "Group by"?

Tags: sql, db2

Say that I have the following table (id_a,id_b,type are actually integers, data is actually xml):

```
id_a   id_b    type     data
-----+------+--------+--------
  1     1       X        X1
  1     1       Y        Y1
  7    17       Y        Y2
  7    99       X        X2
  9    20       Z        Z1
```

The combination of id_a, id_b and type is unique.
Now a program that I write gets as input a list of types that I care for. Say that this list contains X and Y. Now I want to do some SQL-Magic that ends up with the following result:

```
id_a   id_b      X        Y
-----+------+--------+--------
  1      1      X1        Y1
  7      17     NULL      Y2
  7      99     X2        NULL
```

In words: I want a row that contains all data for id_a and id_b, listing the data in columns.

I was able to find a query by myself that ends up with the following table:

```
table:
id_a   id_b   data_x   data_y
-----+------+--------+--------
  1     1       X1      NULL
  1     1       NULL       Y1
  7    17       NULL       Y2
  7    99       X2       NULL
```

The query:

```
select
  id_a,
  id_b,
  case when type = 'X' then data
  end data_x,
  case when type = 'Y' then data
  end data_y,
from
  mytable
order by
  id_a,id_b
```

In this table it is guaranteed that

- At maximum one of data_x or data_y may be non-NULL (both NULL is ok as well, but that can of course easily be filtered by a `where data_x is not null or data_y is not null`)
- data_x and data_y are both unique for the combination of id_a and id_b.

And if I could now do an `select coalesce(case ... data_y),coalesce(case ... data_y) from ... group by id_a,id_b` then I believe I would be where I want to be, but unfortunately coalesce is not an aggregate function but a scalar function.

In my client application (written in Java) I can of course iterate over the rows, merging the rows, but that seems not very elegant ;-). Is there a "pretty" way to solve this?

I am using DB2 V9.7, but I would prefer a portable solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives the result you want:

```
create table myTable (
    id_a int not null,
    id_b int not null,
    type char(1) not null,
    data varchar(10),
    unique (id_a, id_b, type)
);

insert into myTable values (1, 1, 'X', 'X1');
insert into myTable values (1, 1, 'Y', 'Y1');
insert into myTable values (7, 17, 'Y', 'Y2');
insert into myTable values (7, 99, 'X', 'X2');
insert into myTable values (9, 20, 'Z', 'Z1');

select coalesce(X.id_a, Y.id_a) as id_a, coalesce(X.id_b, Y.id_b) as id_b, 
        X.data as X, Y.data as Y
    from (select * from myTable where type = 'X') X 
        full outer join (select * from myTable Y where type = 'Y') Y 
            on X.id_a = Y.id_a and X.id_b = Y.id_b
```

result

```
 ID_A ID_B X    Y
 ---- ---- ---- ----
    1    1 X1   Y1
    7   17 NULL Y2
    7   99 X2   NULL
```

Comment: quite smart, yes... Hard decision between you solution and Dems' solution. For now I picked yours :-).

Answer (score 2):

Use MAX?

```
SELECT
  id_a,
  id_b,
  MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'X' THEN data END) AS data_x,
  MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'Y' THEN data END) AS data_y
FROM
  myTable
GROUP BY
  id_a,
  id_b
```

**EDIT**

If you can't use aggregate functions, does something like this fit your needs?

```
SELECT
  map.id_a,
  map.id_b,
  myTableX.data AS data_x,
  myTableY.data AS data_y
FROM
  (SELECT id_a, id_b FROM myTable GROUP BY id_a, id_b) AS map
LEFT JOIN
  myTable AS myTableX
    ON  myTalbeX.id_a = map.id_a
    AND myTableX.id_b = map.id_b
    AND myTableX.type = 'X'
LEFT JOIN
  myTable AS myTableY
    ON  myTalbeY.id_a = map.id_a
    AND myTableY.id_b = map.id_b
    AND myTableY.type = 'Y'
```

Comment: Good idea, but: "Each argument must be an expression that returns a value of any built-in data type other than a CLOB, DBCLOB, BLOB, ROWID, or XML" (DB2 manual about MAX). Unfortunately my "data"-column is of type XML :-(.

Comment: nice solution, thank you :-). Though I eventually settled on Frans' solution, I think both are doing fine...

Comment: I'm on DB2, and this is (the revised answer) about how I'd approach it - although I'd likely use a CTE instead of just a table reference (mostly through force of habit).

Answer (score 0):

You still need to do something to bring the data which appear in different records into the same record of the result set.  To do this, you need to use an aggregate function, e.g. max, min.  I don't have access to DB2, but it is pretty similar to Oracle in many respects.  The following works just fine on Oracle.

```
with tmp as 
 (select 1 id_a, 1  id_b, 'X' type_, 'X1' data_ from dual union
  select 1 id_a, 1  id_b, 'Y' type_, 'Y1' data_ from dual union
  select 7 id_a, 17 id_b, 'Y' type_, 'Y2' data_ from dual union
  select 7 id_a, 99 id_b, 'X' type_, 'X2' data_ from dual union
  select 9 id_a, 20 id_b, 'Z' type_, 'Z1' data_ from dual)
select distinct 
       id_a, 
       id_b,
       max(decode(type_, 'X', data_, null)) data_x,
       max(decode(type_, 'Y', data_, null)) data_y  
  from tmp  
 group by id_a, id_b
```

**EDIT:**
For a non-aggregate version, you can use this:

```
    with tmp as 
     (select 1 id_a, 1  id_b, 'X' type_, 'X1' data_ from dual union
      select 1 id_a, 1  id_b, 'Y' type_, 'Y1' data_ from dual union
      select 7 id_a, 17 id_b, 'Y' type_, 'Y2' data_ from dual union
      select 7 id_a, 99 id_b, 'X' type_, 'X2' data_ from dual union
      select 9 id_a, 20 id_b, 'Z' type_, 'Z1' data_ from dual)
    select nvl(x.id_a, y.id_a) id_a, nvl(x.id_b, y.id_b) id_b, x.data_, y.data_ 
      from tmp x
           full outer join tmp y
             on (    x.id_a = y.id_a
                 and x.id_b = y.id_b
                 and x.type_ = 'X'
                 and y.type_ = 'Y')
 where x.data_ like 'X%' or  y.data_ like 'Y%'
```

Comment: Yes, I need an aggregate function, but unfortunately that's pretty much the same as Dems' answer. I can't use max(), because data is of type XML.

Comment: In the revised anser, you need to filter the `tmp` table to be just 'X' or just 'Y' *before* the full outer join.  At present the join allows `tmp x` to contain everything, then only join `tmp y` based on your predicates.  Also, the where clause then eliminates any records where `x.data_` or `y.data_` are `NULL`.

Comment: Hi @Dems .  You might want to try running it as it is.  It works just fine for me.  Please note that the filtering of `tmp x` and `tmp y` to be just 'X' or just 'Y' occurs in the `on` clause.